# Как понять нагрузку на сервер?

Tags: linux, сервер, centos, веб-сервер, статистика

может кто-то объяснить как понять вот эти цифры?
[image]
то что они показывают нагрузку на 1 минуту, 5 минут и 15 минут - знаю

а что означает например 0.67?

у нас 2 процессора по 12 ядер каждый

до какого значения должно быть максимум нагрузка чтобы чтобы сервер работал нормально?

Comment: Проведите нагрузочное тестирование. Поймёте, при каких параметрах сервер работает нормально, при каких тормозит.

Comment: Сервер работал нормально или вы себя на нем комфортно ощущали? Я обычно стараюсь интерактивно работать на серверах у которых load average меньше половины количества ядер (`grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l`) на нем

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Показатель Load Average показывает, сколько в среднем процессов в системе стояло в очереди на выполнение и выполнялось в каждом из трёх указанных промежутков времени. Здесь «стоит в очереди на выполнение» означает, что процесс не находится в состоянии "sleep" и не ожидает завершения операции ввода-вывода, но и не является выполняющимся в данный квант процеесорного времени. То есть ему не мешает стать выполняющимся ничего, кроме того факта, что процессор в данный момент занят выполнением другого процесса.

Например, если на иначе ничем не занятой одноядерной системе запустить три процесса, занимающихся активными вычислениями чего-либо (то есть не задействующих ввод-вывод), то показатель LA будет находиться в районе чуть выше 3.00.

Что́ есть «сервер работает нормально» обычно точно не известно, поэтому, как уже отметили в комментарии, надо проводить нагрузочное тестирование. Иногда и при достаточно низких показателях LA, но при сильной нагрузке на диск производительность сервера начинает проваливаться заметно раньше теоретического «LA / кол-во ядер > 1», но я обычно рассматриваю именно это значение (то есть когда LA больше, чем количество ядер/HT-потоков) как предельное, при достижении которого процессор сервера явно нуждается в апгрейде (или ПО — в оптимизации). Или, по-другому выражаясь, неизвестно, будете ли вы отмечать тормоза при LA < 24, но то, что при LA > 24 вы их точно будете отмечать — это к бабке не ходи.

Answer (score 7):

**htop + F2 (Load +)**

[image: htop + F2 (Load +)]

Средние значения нагрузки в Linux — это «средние значения нагрузки системы», показывающие потребность в исполняемых потоках (задачах) в виде усреднённого количества исполняемых и ожидающих потоков. Это мера нагрузки, которая может превышать обрабатываемую системой в данный момент

а что означает например 0.67? (нагрузку ,была на 15 мин назад  )

*Load Average — среднее значение загруженности системы за период времени (в дальнейшем LA). Три значения показывают усреднённую нагрузку за последние 1, 5 и 15 минут. LA является одним из самых спорных показателей. Можно найти множество противоречивых статей, какое значение считать нормальным. Обычно принимается, что значение 0 это простой ядра, а значение 1 это полная нагрузка ядра. Оценить показатель средней нагрузки можно только зная количество ядер в системе. Узнать сколько ядер доступно можно командой:*

```
dmidecode -t processor | grep "Core Enabled:"
Core Enabled: 6
Core Enabled: 6
```

*Видим, что на данной системе находится 12 физических ядер (6+6). Соответственно, нормальный показатель LA должен быть менее 12.*

- Смотри atop